# Why does lua have function data type?

Tags: lua

why are function considered data type in lua?
you can assign functions to variables and pass them as arguments in python too but there is no function data type in python.

Comment: Maybe to make it easier to store function in variables and to pass it around as arguments to other functions? In Lua functions are [first-class objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), similar to many [functional programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: but you can do that too in python and still functions are not data types in python. right?

Comment: In Python, have you tried doing e.g. `type(some_function)`?

Comment: Yes, `type(lambda:42)` gives `<type 'function'>`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaken.

If you take a look into https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#types

You'll find that Python even has multiple function types.

Callable types:

- user defined function
- user defined methods
- generator functions
- built-in functions
- built-in methods
- ...

There are further sections in the Python documentation that provide detail on the various types the interpreter supports.

Why there is a function type? I guess because it makes sense in a typed language to have different types for different kinds of things. If you don't have different types you don't need types at all. Having a function type is just consequent. How else would you classify a reference to a function?

Answer (score 0):

Python does actually have a function type, its just called `lambda`. In both of these programming languages, functions are first-class values which is just a fancy way of saying you can pass them around to functions just like numbers or strings. It makes it possible to use [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) as a paradigm if it fits your purposes and the problem you are solving.